# Ajax Post request in Dojo not working

Tags: dojo

I'm new to DOJO and following the documentation on Dojo official website i wrote my code for POST request as below. But its not working and its giving me error **"Unable to load myURL status: 0"**.
Please help.

```
 require(["dojo/request","dojo/dom","dojo/on"],function(request,dom,on){

    try{
//Access TextFields Value
var txt_UserName=dom.byId("usrName");
var txt_Password=dom.byId("password");

//Attaching click event on Button   
on(dom.byId("loginButton"),"click",function(evt){
    //alert(txt_UserName.value);
    request.post(myURL,{
        handleAs: "json",   
        data:{
            userId: txt_UserName.value,
            password: txt_Password.value,
        },
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        alert(response);
    },

    function(error){

        alert(error);
    }
);

});

}
catch(error){

    alert(error.message);
}});
```

Comment: I don't see myUrl defined anywhere, nor does dojo. Any reason for the try block?

Comment: @Phix :I have defined myURL as global variable. It will return me JSON and try block i just added to detect some syntax errors.You can ignore try block.

Comment: The error message makes me believe that the value of myURL is "myURL".  Can you add an alert/console.debug to your code before posting and output the value of myURL?

Comment: @Craig: I have tried giving complete URL directly in place of 'myURL'. Its showing the same result "Unable to load Status 0"

Comment: What is the URL?  It has to be relative to the web server that you are on (/service/login) and not a full path (www.yourserver.com/service/login)